# Rotating the credentials in SP metadata

Tags: metadata, saml-2.0

I want to rotate the credentials in the SP metadata. Suppose If I change the credentials at the backend, use these credentials for signing AuthNrequest and publish new SP metadata and if clients does not **immediately update the SP metadata**, then communication between SP and IDP will be broken, as IDP will be using old credentials (old SP metadata (i.e., they have not updated the SP Metadata at the IDP Side with new SP metadata after the credentials changed) to decrypt the assertion.
Now, what is the process of providing graceful time where old credentials continues to work along with new credentials.
Requirements:

1. We should not force Clients to update SP metadata during this grace period (i.e., we should not break the communication between SP and IDP, even though credentials at the backend got rotated to new one).
2. Backend code to be written in Golang.
3. Minimal to no efforts needed by clients to update IDP at there end during the grace period.

I have explored few options:

Maintain Both Sets of Credentials: Instead of immediately changing the credentials at the SP's backend, maintain both the old and new credentials simultaneously during the transitional period.

Dual Encryption/Signing: Configure the SP to perform dual encryption and signing for SAML assertions. This means that the SP will encrypt and sign each assertion twice: once with the old credentials and once with the new credentials.

Send Dual Encrypted/Signed Assertions: When the SP sends SAML assertions to the IdP, it includes both the old and new encrypted/signed assertions within the same message. This allows the IdP to decrypt and verify the assertions using either the old or new credentials.

IdP Handling of Dual Assertions: The IdP needs to be updated to handle the dual encrypted/signed assertions. It should be configured to decrypt and verify both sets of assertions using the respective credentials. During the transitional period, the IdP should accept and process assertions encrypted and signed with either the old or new credentials.

but above ask requires IDP to support dual encryption/signing. Assuming that we have more than 1000 clients, we cannot expect every IDP to support above ask, so we may not be able to implement above ask.
Even though IDP supports dual encryption/signing and if client has not enabled it, we need to ask them to enable before we push the code to the production.

Are there any alternatives where there is smooth transition from old to new with minimal to no involvement of configuring/update needed at the IDP side by clients.